# Can I set the background of a SCNScene from the scene editor in Xcode?

Tags: swift, swiftui, scenekit

This might be a stupid question, but how can I set the background of my scene from the Scene editor itself ? I want the Scene to be transparent so I can overlay it on top of UI, for now I do it in code :

```swift
func initMainScene() -> SCNScene {
    guard let newScene = SCNScene(named : "mainScene.scn")
        else { fatalError("Unable to load scene file.") }
    newScene.background.contents = UIColor.clear
    return newScene
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the scene background color can be edited in the very last inspector on the right (named "Scene Inspector", with shortcut <kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>⌥</kbd><kbd>8</kbd>)